# Upload two files

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, image-uploading

I'm about to go crazy.. I am trying upload two files but with no result

```
<input name="post_image" type="file" class="file">
<input name="post_image_2" type="file" class="file">
```

And php

```
if ($_FILES) {
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
            if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                echo "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                die();
            }
            $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
        }   
    }
```

But it loop all files and assigns file to $attach_id. So I tried make

```
foreach ($_FILES['post_image'] as $file => $array) {
    if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
        die();
        }
        $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
    }
```

and the same for `$_FILES['post_image_2']` 
but then i got 
`Undefined index: name, type, tmp_name, error... in..`

I expected $attach_id and $attach_id_2 as result

Comment: both codes are not working?

Comment: first works but it loop all files and assigns file to $attach_id. I want upload two files and assign it for two variables.

Comment: you have two input fields so it should loop two files? all files means?

Comment: yes. So how get result of 1st and 2nd uploaded files?

Comment: what do you mean by it loops all files?

Comment: Every file which was posted. And every time it assign upload result to $attach_id, but I have two files and want to $attach_id_1 and $attach_id_2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115429/discussion-between-muhammad-sumon-molla-selim-and-user3041764).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this way:

```
if ($_FILES) {
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
            if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                echo "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                die();
            }
            $var = 'attach_id_'.$i;
            $$var = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
            $i++;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but... when user fill only second file input then second file will save as attach_id_1.

Comment: so what do you want, if there's no file you want to still keep attach_id_1?